# TextInput cursor pointer remains on screen after component unmounts

Tags: react-native

The cursor pointer remains like a ghost from the past after having selected a `<TextInput/>` in a previous screen. Switching screens doesn't make it go away, pressing it doesn't do anything - it just floats there in the same spot. In fact, the screenshot below had two pointers from the same TextInput but the left one disappeared after a little while, while the other one stuck around (pun intended :) Anyone else experience this?

Environment:

Android 5.1.1

react: 16.3.1

react-native: ~0.55.2

[image: Screenshot of cursor pointer remaining on screen]

Comment: Maybe your phone is Samsung?

Comment: That is a very incriminating assumption - and you are correct! XD That is why I have a Pixel on the way.

Comment: Have you found any solution regarding this ? I have been facing the same issue on my Samsung J3 Pro (5.1.1).

Comment: Nope. But as stated, it is a Samsung related problem - or possibly Android 5.1.1 since my device at the time when this was still occuring was running that version. So I'd say don't sweat it too much.

Comment: Same on Samsung Galaxy Tab A. Also running Android 5.1.1

Comment: Also seeing this on Samsung Tab Active 1 and react-native 0.63.4